# c# Add Soundfile to Setup and direct to file path

Tags: c#, file, path, installation

I want to create a SetupFile for my project. I have two sounds that I use... that's my current code (which works fine when I debug):

```
SoundPlayer clckSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\My Name\Downloads\Button Push.wav");
SoundPlayer wonSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\My Name\Downloads\Applause.wav");
```

Inside my Setup Project in the "Application Folder" I created another folder named "Assets" where I put the two sound files.

I tried it with the following code which didnt work.

```
SoundPlayer clckSound = new SoundPlayer(Application.StartupPath + "\\Assets\\Button Push.wav");
SoundPlayer wonSound = new SoundPlayer(Application.StartupPath + "\\Assets\\Applause.wav");
```

How do I specify the file path in my code so that the sounds get played properly after installation of the Setup file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Whats the folder relationship between Assets and the executable of your application?

Comment: The exacutable is in the "Application Folder" together with the "Assets" folder.